# Showing boundedness of a set (preparation for the proof of the Young inequality)

Tags: upper-lower-bounds, young-inequality

Define the two sets:

$\Omega = \{(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \; | \; a>0, b>0\}, \; \; \; \; \overline{\Omega} = \{(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \; | \; a\ge0, b\ge0\}$

as well as the functions

$g: \overline{\Omega} \to \mathbb{R}, \; \; g(a,b) = \frac{a^p}{p}+\frac{b^q}{q} \; \; , \; a,b \ge 0\\ f: \overline{\Omega} \to \mathbb{R}, \; \; f(a,b) = ab, \; \; a,b \ge 0$.

Furthermore, let c > 0 and consider the sets

$M_c = \{(a,b) \in \Omega \; | \; g(a,b) - c = 0\}\;$ and $\;\overline{M_{c}} = \{(a,b) \in \overline{\Omega} \; | \; g(a,b) -c = 0\}$

---

The task is: show, that the set $\overline{M_{c}}$ is bounded.

I tried defining the two functions $g_1: \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0} \to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}, \; \; a \mapsto g(a,0) \text{ and } \\
g_2: \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0} \to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}, b \mapsto g(0,b)$

As $g_1, g_2$ are strictly monotonic increasing and unlimited, consequently the preimages $g_1^{-1}(c) = \{a_0\}$ and $g_2^{-1}(c) = \{b_0\}$ are bounded. However for this to work, I have to show, that for all $(a,b) \in \overline{M_c}$ the following inequality holds: $a \le a_0$ and $b \le b_0$. This would then imply the boundedness of the $\overline{M_c}$.

How could this be shown? And is my approach constructive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing that $\overline M_c$ is bounded is trivial: If $(a,b)\in\overline M_c$ then$$\frac{a^p}p\le\frac{a^p}p+\frac{b^q}q= c,$$so $$a\le{(cp)}^{1/p}.$$Similarly $$b\le(cq)^{1/q}.$$So $\overline M_c$ is contained in a (bounded) rectangle.

Comment: This is much easier than I thought!

Comment: This is a good answer. Please do not delete good content.

Comment: @robjohn that's what I thought, but I was wrong. It just adds noise to the site.

Comment: This question is not a PSQ. Please do not take any messages about the quality standards to imply that your *answers* are in any way noise; your answers are exemplary, and I myself believe that a good answer is worthwhile in itself.  However, it is also the quality of the *questions* that are under scrutiny by the community here, and the quality standards are being enforced to reduce the immense number of such questions that are flooding the site (whether they are interesting or not).

Comment: As a result, moderators are contacting users to notify them of the [EoQS](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). The idea is to encourage the asker to improve their post to meet community standards before answering the question.  The standard message sent is somewhat unfriendly. I am looking into making that a bit friendlier and explanatory of the problems we face.

Comment: @robjohn I thought we had a policy that third-party edits are ok _if_the editor is certain the edit is consistent with the author's intent. Do you really think your rollbacks satisfy that condition?

Comment: @robjohn Thanks for the kind words. I didn't see anything "unfriendly" about the message I got - I'd call it egregiously insulting. I'm not taking anything to "imply" anything: the message _stated_ that my _answers_ do nothing but add noise. (No, they were not referring to _all_ my answers. Hell of a way to tun a railroad - solicit free contributions from official experts, then keep the contributions you like and shower abuse on the ones you don't like. If I were desperate for the privilege of being allowed to help MSE construct a site just exactly the way they want it I'd go along with that.)

Comment: I don't think that there is any doubt that this answer is good. Deletion or defacement of good content is not in keeping with site policy. My rollbacks were only to undo that defacement of site content (the answer is site content according to the site license).

Comment: I see that the use of the word "only" in "serves only to contribute noise to the site" does imply things that were not intended to be implied. It is not the answer that is adding noise, but the encouragement of PSQs that occurs from answering such questions. Thank you for pointing this out. A form message is often not the best way to go, but in order  to handle the number of cases we have, a compromise was made. As I said, I am looking into making that form message better.

Comment: @robjohn by all means try to make it better. makes no difference to me, i'm outa here

Comment: I will personally be very upset if you leave. I find your contributions very beneficial to myself and the site. Please don't take a form message as a personal attack.

Comment: @robjohn I'd have to be pathologically modest not to believe that a lot of people find, or have found, my contributions very useful. But MSE disagrees, and it's their site - they have the right to tell me my answers are doing nothing but add noise, but if they expect me to stick around after that they're crazy.

Comment: Defacing posts is not an option. We can discuss various things, but defacing is a no go. The changes were undone and will continue to be undone.

Comment: @quid Given that they're officially just adding noise I don't see why MSE is not happy to simply delete them all as I requested.